# Поиск и удаление совпадений в строке

Tags: массивы, php

Существует список чисел через запятую, возможно с повторяющимися значениями.
Например:

```
207, 47, 207, 205, 28, 43, 210, 28, 210, 43, 254, 28, 209, 28, 212, 43, 28, 210, 43, 28, 205, 34, 45, 46, 210, 254, 212, 207, 210, 212, 43, 210, 207, 209, 28, 28, 254, 254, 210, 205, 210, 35, 207, 43, 43, 38, 254, 28, 35, 212, 205, 40, 210, 43, 207, 209, 47,
```

Список может быть любой длины. Цифры могут быть разными.
Как найти и удалить повторения, вывести остальные значения на экран без запятых в виде, н-р:

```
<ul>
<li>207</li>
<li>47</li>
<li>205</li>
...
</ul>
```

Может есть какие-то регулярки для поиска и удаления дублирований?

Comment: зачем строка? Лучше цифры хранить в массиве. Что сложного создать 2-й массив из первого исключив повторения?

Comment: Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все очень просто, если вооружиться google и http://php.net

```
<?php
$old = array("foo", "bar", "hallo", "hallo", "hallo", "world");//создайте массив нужных значений
$new = array_unique($old);//уберите лишнее
 //убедитесь, что все работает
echo "<pre>";
echo "С повторениями: <br />";
print_r($old);
unset($old);//уничтожить старый массив
echo "Без повторениями: <br />";
print_r($new);
echo "</pre>";

//собственно задание

 "echo "======================================";
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($new as  $value) {
        echo "<li>".$value."</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
?>
```

результатом будет:

```
С повторениями: 
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => bar
    [2] => hallo
    [3] => hallo
    [4] => hallo
    [5] => world
)
Без повторениями: 
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => bar
    [2] => hallo
    [5] => world
)
   ======================================
```

- foo
- bar
- hallo
- world

Enjoy.

Comment: Это для понимания процесса, что бы упростить код можно написать так
$array = array_unique($array);
что бы не создавать, а потом не удалять лишних переменных

Comment: Супер! Спасибо, помогло.

Comment: А как подсчитать сколько получилось уникальных $value в массиве?

Comment: тоже легко, только уже не страндартной функцией, а проверяйте циклом по массиву выражением if(in_array($value)){$counter++}, потом, по завершению цикла $counter и будет содержать кол-вот одинаковых.

Comment: все, уже знаю... count($value);
^)